# Xcode: How to open several tabs within the same project?

Tags: xcode, eclipse, file

I have attached two pictures with this question, the first is in Eclipse and the second is Xcode.

What I am trying to do in Xcode is to open several workspaces to write different code within the same project.
For now, every time I want to try a different version of my original code to compare the two codes I have to create a new project. 
Any Advice?

[image: Eclipse]

[image: Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to quickly run different files without creating other projects, here is something you could do :

- Create a new file and add it to your project (cmd+N)
- Put your alternative code in there
- Click on your project, go to Build Phases and ONLY RETAIN the files you want to compile

[image: here the two versions are contained in main and main2]